# Register a Gstreamer1.0 Python Element? Wanting to react to bus element messages

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am new to Gstreamer, so I apologize if this question is very simple, but I've been stuck for way too long.

I'm using Mopidy on my raspberry pi to play music through speakers.  When Mopidy is playing, I want to be able to able to stobe some lights in sync with the low-band, mids, and highs.  By my understanding, Mopidy uses Gstreamer on the backend, and you can customize the pipeline by specifying

```
[audio]
output= spectrum bands=3 ! autoaudiosink
```

I need to put something between spectrum and the sink that will analyze the element messages being posted on the bus by 'spectrum' (unless somebody has a better idea).  I'm trying to write a simple element in python that passes through the audio but has a message handling element that can implement my custom logic.  However, I cannot even get started with simple online examples because I do not know how to get the element registered for gstreamer to recognize it.  When I follow the gst-python identity.py example at https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-python/blob/master/examples/plugins/python/identity.py , the prescribed instructions do not work.

```
    jlc@FuzzPi:~/Rise $ export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=$GST_PLUGIN_PATH:$PWD
    jlc@FuzzPi:~/Rise $ GST_DEBUG=python:4 gst-launch-1.0 fakesrc num-buffers=10 ! identity_py ! fakesink
    WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "identity_py"
```

I've tried every conceivable GST_PLUGIN_PATH, and tried everything in every online post I could find, and I'm likely just missing something incredibly basic, but I really could use a hand figuring out what it is that I'm missing!  From what I can tell, this should not be this complicated.

My OS is Ubuntu MATE 16.04, and all of my gstreamer packages are version >1.6

```
jlc@FuzzPi:~/Rise $ dpkg -l | grep gst
ii  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0            1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                           armhf        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer Plugins Base library
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0                   1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                          armhf        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:armhf                1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                           armhf        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0               3.0.18-1                                   armhf        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:armhf               1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                           armhf        libav plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-nice:armhf                0.1.13-0ubuntu2                            armhf        ICE library (GStreamer plugin)
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:armhf        1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                           armhf        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:armhf        1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                           armhf        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:armhf        1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1                           armhf        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:armhf    1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1                           armhf        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:armhf          1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                           armhf        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                     1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                          armhf        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:armhf                   1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                           armhf        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libclutter-gst-3.0-0:armhf             3.0.18-1                                   armhf        Open GL based interactive canvas library GStreamer elements
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:armhf   1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                           armhf        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:armhf   1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                           armhf        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:armhf                1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                          armhf        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer  1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1               armhf        GStreamer backend for LibreOffice
ii  python-gst-1.0                         1.6.2-1build1                              armhf        GStreamer GObject Introspection overrides for Python
ii  python-gst-1.0-dbg                     1.6.2-1build1                              armhf        GStreamer GObject Introspection overrides for Python (debug extensions)
```

Comment: These links might help https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gst-1.0/Gst.Plugin.html and https://pastebin.com/gyv3V45S , although the pastebin example is based on GstVideo

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I see that running the pastebin example with python created the element, and registered it for use later in the program.  But how would I make it so that NewElement is runnable from gst-launch-1.0?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you figure it out?